# SqlDataAdapter with 2 queries doesnt give the right o/p

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Contentpagenav;Select * from Employees",conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        conn.Open();
        adap.TableMappings.Add("ContentPagenav", "Table1");
        adap.TableMappings.Add("Employees", "Table2");
        adap.Fill(ds, "Table1");
        adap.Fill(ds, "Table2");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table2"];
        GridView2.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
```

I am getting the first table data in both the gridviews. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there are some mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried by doing this

```
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Contentpagenav;Select * from Employees",conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    conn.Open();
    // don't map
    //adap.TableMappings.Add("ContentPagenav", "Table1");
    //adap.TableMappings.Add("Employees", "Table2");
    //adap.Fill(ds, "Table1");
    //adap.Fill(ds, "Table2");

    // access tables by index instead of name
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
    GridView2.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
```

**Edit 1:**  **There are some mistakes with your code**

```
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Contentpagenav;Select * from Employees",conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
conn.Open();
// the select statement only return Table, Table1, Table2 and so on
// it don't know About ContentPagenav or Employees
// so I am maping Table to MyTable1
//and Table1 to MyTable2
adap.TableMappings.Add("Table", "MyTable1");
adap.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "MyTable2");

// don't do this, it will discard your mapping,
// it will return
// Table1, Table2, and so on
//adap.Fill(ds, "Table1");

// just fill your dataset, and it will keep your mapping
adap.Fill(ds);

// access tables by your suggested name
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["MyTable1"];
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["MyTable2"];
GridView2.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```

For more understandings [Table Mapping in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810286.aspx)

Comment: It works with the index as you have mentioned. I was actually wondering why is tablemappings used for?

Comment: To be precise! I learned from this page.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810286.aspx